# How to make Python argparse correctly interpret an argument that matches a command?

Tags: python, argparse

Suppose I have the following setup:

```
parser.add_argument('-v', '--version', help='Print version',  action='version', version=VERSION)
parser.add_argument('-a', '--analyse', help='Analyse command execution',  nargs='*', action='append')
```

The command `analyse` receives `n` options to be analysed. These options might match the signature of commands `--version` and/or `--help`. Examples:

1. `cli --analyse key1 --version`
2. `cli --analyse key2 --help`
3. `cli --analyse key1 --version key2 --help`

If I run 1, 2 or 3, instead of proceeding to `analyse` execution, `argparse` executes:

- `--version` for 1;
- `--help` for 2;
- `--version` for 3;

**For the given scenarions, where the command starts with `--analyse`, I want that the subsequent `--version` and `--help` to be interpreted as options of `analyse` and not the commands which they match the signature. Is that possible?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `argparse.Remainder` (explanation in the [last bullet point here in the doc](https://docs.python.org/3/library/argparse.html#nargs)):

```
import argparse

VERSION = "1.0"
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description='Argparse test')
parser.add_argument('-v', '--version', help='Print version',  action='version', version=VERSION)
parser.add_argument('-a', '--analyse', help='Analyse command execution',  nargs=argparse.REMAINDER, action='append')
args = parser.parse_args()

if args.analyse:
    print(args.analyse)
```

Comment: Great! There is just one situation where it didn't work. For multiple commands posted at once with the short version, e.g.: `cli -a k1 v1 -a k2 v2` gives me wrong signature, however, `cli --analytics k1 v1 --analytics k2 v2` works fine. Thank you anyways, I should look into the docs more carefully!

Comment: I am surprised that it works for you with `cli --analyse k1 v1 --analyse k2 v2`. It should only accept one analyse option and then interpret the rest of the commands as arguments of that option, including all further instances of `--analyse` and `-a`.

Comment: You are right, it is interpreting the rest as list. By "work" I meant compatibility with the old command processing logic. I'll have to tweak that a bit in order to process the args as a list instead of the way I was doing. Thanks once more.